# Spree 2.0.4 change _variables.scss

Tags: sass, spree

I'm using Spree 2.0.4 and I want to change the light blue link/price color globally.  I found `app/assets/stylesheets/store/_variables.scss` and changed `$link_text_color` but it doesn't seem to effect the appearance.

I'm unfamiliar with scss, the internet seems to say I may need to use some kind of `sass --watch` command, but I can't figure out the implementation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern version of Rails handle assets through the [Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), so you don't need to worry about compiling your scss files with sass watch.

Unfortunately, I believe the issue you're encountering is currently an outstanding issue in Spree:
https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/3415